# Log4net RollingFileAppender not working properly

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using Log4net to create a log for console application execution. it is working fine in my DEV environment but having an issue in Production environment.

My application running 5 times a day. On first execution, it is creating one log file and for rest of execution, it is creating another file with the date appended two times.. like below:-

- Exception 2018-09-15.log
- Exception 2018-09-15Exception 2018-09-15.log
- Exception 2018-09-16.log
- Exception 2018-09-16Exception 2018-09-16.log
- Exception 2018-09-17.log
- Exception 2018-09-17Exception 2018-09-17.log

I found the solution like it is initiating two times but in this case, it should create 5 file instead of 2 files.

Thanks in advance.

App.config:-

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" 
  type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net" />
  </configSections>
<!-- Log4net Logging Setup -->
<log4net>
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</root>
 <logger additivity="false" name="ManpowerFCST_Logger">
  <level value="ALL" />
  <appender-ref ref="ManpowerFCST_Logger" />
</logger>

 <appender name="ManpowerFCST_Logger" 
 type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
  value="C:\Users\HAS\Manpower_FCST_UAT\Audit Log\.log" />
   <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="'Audit 'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10KB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="False" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - 
%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="RollingFileAppender" 
 type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
value="C:\Users\HAS\Manpower_FCST_UAT\Exception Log\.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" /> 
 <datePattern value="'Exception 'yyyy-MM-dd"/> 
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
   <maxSizeRollBackups value="100" /> 
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="False" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger 
%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Hi, try changing `<datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd"/>` and `<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
value="C:\Users\HAS\Manpower_FCST_UAT\Exception Log\Exception.log" />` same changes with your analog audio logs

Comment: hi @nilsK thanks for your response.. but with the same configuration Audit Log files are creating in correct way.. per day one file. I am having issue with Exception Log files why that so?

Comment: Not sure if i got you right. `<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
  value="C:\Users\HAS\Manpower_FCST_UAT\Audit Log\Audit.log" />` and `<datePattern value="yyyy-MM-dd"/>` would be the config tags for audit log files [*Edit:* copy&paste fail ... my bad].

Comment: I am creating two log file .. Audit and Exception with same config as mentioned above.
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
  value="C:\Users\HAS\Manpower_FCST_UAT\Audit Log\.log" />
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" 
value="C:\Users\HAS\Manpower_FCST_UAT\Exception Log\.log" />

Audit log file is creating perfectly but not Exception Log file.

Comment: So my doubt is why to change in existing functionality if it is working fine at one place(audit log) are creating with same config..but not exception log. However is it working fine in DEV environment.

Comment: Okay, got you. I had the same behaviour of generating multiple files with similar naming pattern you have, and the changes i suggested worked for me. Did you test it? `However is it working fine in DEV environment` even when running it multiple times in a row?

Comment: Sorry but it is not working for me..at the same time both the files are created Audit and Exception..after done the changes it is creating like this :-
      Exception2018-09-19.log


      Exception2018-09-192018-09-19.log